# Restructuring 2-level data to 3-level data

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, multi-level, multilevel-analysis

I have a two-level multilevel data. Below is an example of it. I have two participants that reported their fruits consumption for two days.

```
id day apple orange
1   1    34     12
1   2    54     43
2   1    65     56
2   2    87     81
```

I want to restructure the dataframe from 2-level data to 3-level data. I want to a) make a variable for type of fruit; b) nest fruit consumption in days in one column. So the dataframe looks like below:

```
id day fruit_type fruit_consumption
1   1      apple                34
1   1     orange                12
1   2      apple                54
1   2     orange                43
2   1      apple                65
2   1     orange                56
2   2      apple                87
2   2     orange                81
```

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -c(id, day))`

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're are referring to Python's `pandas` `DataFrame` then I've coded for it next solution, a bit generic, not only for two columns apple/orange that need to be rearranged but for any number of columns, controlled by specifying range `crng` in the beginning of script. Should work fast as it uses plain `numpy` with small number of python's loop iterations.

You can also [try next code online here!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64060524#main.py).

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

crng = (2, 4) # Range of columns for rearranging

df = pd.DataFrame([map(int, line.split()) for line in """
    1   1    34     12
    1   2    54     43
    2   1    65     56
    2   2    87     81
""".splitlines() if line.strip()], columns = ['id', 'day', 'apple', 'orange'])
print('input:\n', df)

a = df.values
b = np.zeros((a.shape[0], crng[1] - crng[0], crng[0] + 2), dtype = np.object_)

for icol, col in enumerate(df.columns[crng[0] : crng[1]]):
    b[:, icol, 0] = a[:, 0]
    b[:, icol, 1] = a[:, 1]
    b[:, icol, 2] = df.columns[crng[0] + icol]
    b[:, icol, 3] = a[:, crng[0] + icol]

b = b.reshape((b.shape[0] * b.shape[1], b.shape[2]))

df = pd.DataFrame(data = b,
    columns = df.columns[:crng[0]].values.tolist() + ['fruit_type', 'fruit_consumption'],
)
print('output:\n', df)
```

Comment: Probably you're speaking not about `Python`/`pandas`, then my solution would be still useful for someone else...